# Proxy config won't work on Angular linked to a Node js server

Tags: node.js, angular, proxy

my app is unhappy when I try to call my back from my angular client:

[image: cors issue]

I checked the documentation but also checked several forums but I couldn't solve my issue.
I have first tried to setup a proxy on my client:
**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "info"
    }
}
```

And then ran:

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --verbose
```

I ensured that the proxy was initialized since i got this in my logs:

```
[webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Proxy created: /api  -> http://localhost:3000
```

But I keep getting the same issue...
I tried few variations like adding ***"changeOrigin": true*** and even tried the ***pathRewrite*** but this is probably pointless

Then I tried to change the config of my node js server to resolve the conflict. My **main js** file looks like so:

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const routes = require('./routes/routes');
const API_URL = "/api/v1";

app.use(express.json());
app.use(API_URL, routes);
app.use(cors());

var server = app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(("Server started on PORT 3000"));
})
```

And in my **routes** files I got:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
module.exports = router;

router.get('/getNeedQuery/:query', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        //some processing
        res.status(200).json(//some object);
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(500).json({message: error.message});
    }
})
```

And unfortunately I still get the same issue.

But when I try to directly run the url in my browser, it works for both PORT 4200 and 3000...

Comment: By the looks of it you're not making the request via the proxy. If you visit the endpoint directly of course you don't get CORS problems, proxy or no, because you're not making a cross-origin request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I have finally fixed my issue. Even tho I gave up on the original idea which was to use a proxy.
I have fixed the CORS issue directly in the backend. The solution is not easy to determine when you discover middleware for the first time like me. For any people new to middleware, keep in mind that **the order of declarations is very important** and you really have to know which order is correct. In my case I was setting up the CORS security bypass after configuring the routes so it was ignoring the CORS configuration.

Old order (wrong):

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const routes = require('./routes/routes');
const API_URL = "/api/v1";
app.use(API_URL, routes);
app.use(cors());
```

New order (correct):

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const routes = require('./routes/routes');
const API_URL = "/api/v1";
app.use(cors());
app.use(API_URL, routes);
```

I hope this can help some people :)